# Spline binary logistic regression in R

Tags: r, splines

I am beginner in using R.
I want to run a binary logistic regression and I guess some variables have nonlinearities. So I want to use splines method to understand affect of each range in a continuous variable. I am confused about it.

How can I do it in R ?
Knots (cut points) will determine automatically or I should determine manually ?
How can I know overall p-value of variable ?

```
 model<- lrm(formula = PA ~ rcs(HEIGHT) + SLOPE + ASPECT, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

I do not know "rcs" is helpful or not.. I found it by searching here. I will be grateful if you guide me about it.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by the "overall p-value" of the variable? Do you mean if the variable has *any* impact on the outcome? Then you might be interested in what I have come to like calling ["chunk" testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests).

Comment: True, I want to to know impact of variable that splined.

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/05/classification-from-scratch-logistic-with-splines-2-8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to be using the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R, then you can accomplish what you want directly with that package. There can be something of a learning curve with it. In particular, it works best with data for which a "datadist" has been defined and made available to the software. Take the time to learn it; it's worth it. This [Introduction to the Harrell"verse"](https://www.nicholas-ollberding.com/post/an-introduction-to-the-harrell-verse-predictive-modeling-using-the-hmisc-and-rms-packages/) might be helpful, as would the many examples in Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/).

For your specific question, the default knot locations, based on quantiles of the predictor values, typically work well. You might choose other locations if your prior knowledge of the subject matter indicates a region of predictor values where you expect a large change in outcome. Resist the temptation to play around with knot locations, as then you need to account for that use of the outcomes to define the model. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7317/28500).

I prefer the `rcs()` default knot locations to those in the `ns()` function mentioned in the [answer I just linked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7317/28500), as the outermost knots aren't forced to be at the extreme predictor values. That helps make knot placement less dependent on vagaries of a particular data sample. The `rcspline.eval()` function of the [`Hmisc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc) does the default placement:

> If not given, knots will be estimated using default quantiles of `x`. For 3 knots, the outer quantiles used are 0.10 and 0.90. For 4-6 knots, the outer quantiles used are 0.05 and 0.95. For `nk` > 6, the outer quantiles are 0.025 and 0.975. The knots are equally spaced between these on the quantile scale. For fewer than 100 non-missing values of `x`, the outer knots are the 5th smallest and largest `x`.

One of the great strengths of the `rms` package is that it naturally provides evaluation of *all* terms involving each predictor, with that package's implementation of the `anova()` function for use with its models. That does "chunk tests" on all terms involving individual predictors, whether splines or interactions. That avoids the problem that I think you fear, which is how to interpret a whole set of individual regression coefficients involving a predictor in a typical model summary. When working in `rms`, just using `anova(model)` will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much EdM